# Install4j : Not able to copy installation logs to another location

Tags: install4j

For install4j 5.1.6 , I am trying to add a vm option
and setting its values as "-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true" in the options.
I also tried this option -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=C:\

But if  some error condition occurs the during installation, and installation is cancelled . The logs are not retained 
They get deleted from the temp folder also .
I want to retain the logs , even if the installation was cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

Adding

```
-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true
```

to the "VM parameters" property of the "Installer" on the "Installer->Screens & Actions" step will prevent the log files from being deleted.

The log file in the `%TEMP%` directory has a name that starts with "i4jlog...".

The option

```
-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=c:\path\to\logfile.txt
```

allows you to select a fixed location for the log file. The path must be writable.

Comment: I am trying both options
-Dinstall4j.keepLog=true ; -Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile = d:\test.txt
The logs are retained in the %TEMP%directory
But the logs are not getting copied to the specified path.
I tried giving this in quotes also
-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile = d:\test.txt

But doesn’t work

Comment: I see spaces around your "=" sign. Another question is whether d:\test.txt can be written.